# Bulk insert from share folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have share folder in server `A` with permissions.
and I'm trying to use bulk insert from server `B`.
I've also added network location to server 'B' with 'A'(trying to use the local path - but nothing).
using `sql server 2008 r2` 
the `SQL` authentication is: `Sql server`.
In addition there is no domain controller to those servers, but obviously there are under the same network .
the error is:
Cannot bulk load because the file `\\\server\folder\file` could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
what can I do?
thanks

Comment: You connection string should not use the mdf filename.  Instead the connection string should eliminate the mdf and connect to the server name and instance of SQL Server.  The instance should be the same that appears in SQL Server Management Studio login window.

Comment: Where is your bulk load command? If you use bcp,you need run it on server b and have access to the file from server a. You can also use studio on server a to import data on server a to database on server b.

Comment: the command is from Stored procedure, under Sql authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server process identity (service account) security context is used when the `BULK INSERT` T-SQL statement is invoked from a SQL authenticated connection.  Without a domain infrastructure, you will need to either allow `Everyone` access to the file and share or create a local Windows account on both servers with the same account name and password.  Use that local Windows account as the SQL Server service account (specified via the SQL Server Configuration Manager).

Comment: The permission to everyone didn't help. and I don't want to change the service account. Is there another way?

Comment: @user2145201, create a local account on the file server with the same name and password as the service account.  Also, make sure you grant permissions to both the share and files.